# Tautologous Herbrand Expansion

Tags: first-order-logic

Can someone explain me how to build a herbrand expansion of the following, that is a tautology?

1. $(\exists x) [P(x) \implies (\forall y) P(y)]$
2. $(\exists x) (\forall y) R(x,y) \implies  (\forall y)(\exists x) R(x,y)$

My thought's are to bring these formulas into prenex form and than to skolemize them to remove the existential operator. After that i could write the variables as functions, so that i do not have any variable in the sentence...

For the first sentence i tried this:

1. $(\exists x) [P(x) \implies (\forall y) P(y)]$
2. $(\forall y) (\exists x) [P(x) \implies  P(y)]$
3. $(\forall y) [P(f(y)) \implies  P(y)]$ write x as function of y
4. $[P(f(a)) \implies  P(a)]$ with $[x/a]$

But i don't think that this is right. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: See [PNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication): the first step will produce: $(∃x)(∀y)(P(x) \to P(y))$

Comment: Thank you! If i have any further question, i will write another comment.

Comment: Can i write for the 2. (∃x)(∀y)R(x,y)⟹(∀y)(∃x)R(x,y) in the first step  (∃x)(∀y)(R(x,y)⟹R(x,y)) ? And then (∃x)(∀y)(¬R(x,y) ∨  R(x,y))?

Comment: Not exactly: the scope of quantifiers are different. Maybe $R(a,y) \to R(x, f(x))$ that means $\lnot R(a,y) \lor R(x,f(x))$. Then you have to use *unification*.

Comment: Is $R(a,y) \implies R(x, f(x))$ your first step? Or, why did you $R(a,y) \implies R(x, f(x))$and not $R(x,y) \implies R(f(y), y)$ ? What will be your tautologous herbrand expansion in this case?

Comment: You are right :-)

Comment: Can you show me your steps between R(x,y)⟹R(f(y),y) and ¬R(a,y)∨R(f(y),y)?
I don not understand how $\exists x \forall y R(x,y)$ comes to R(a,y)...

Comment: Okay i got it. But why should ¬R(a,y)∨R(f(y),y) a tautology? For this my herbrand-universe is {a, f(a)} isn`t it? You are saving my exam this semester. Thank you very much Mauro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if a formula is *valid* (a "FOL tautology") we have to consider its negation.

For the first one [which is valid; see [Drinker's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox)], we have: $\lnot (∃x)[P(x) \to (∀y)P(y)]$.

We start removing $\to$ and moving inside the negation sign, getting:

> $(\forall x)[P(x) \land \lnot (∀y)P(y)]$.

Now we considere [PNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) to get: $(\forall x)P(x) \land \lnot (\forall y)P(y)$, i.e.

> $(\forall x)P(x) \land (\exists y) \lnot P(y)$, which is clearly *unsatisfiable*.

In order to complete the proof using [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), we have to consider the two *clauses*:

> $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(a)$,

where we have applied [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#Examples):

> An existential quantifier that is not preceded by a universal one must be replaced by an individual constant (a $0$-ary function).

Finally, we apply [Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) with the substitution $\sigma := [x \leftarrow a]$ and we produce the *empty clause*, showing that the negated formula is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. that the original formula is *valid*.

---

For the second one, we start again considering its negation, and we have two clauses: $(∃x)(∀y)R(x,y)$ and $\lnot (∀y)(∃x)R(x,y)$, 
i.e.

> $(∃x)(∀y)R(x,y)$ and $(∃y)(∀x) \lnot R(x,y)$.

Applying again Skolemization we get: $R(a,y)$ and $\lnot R(x,a)$.

An easy substitution will unify them.

---

---

For details you can see e.g. Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science (Springer, 3rd ed. 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA181).